# How to make edge half cylinder in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

I want to make selected edge to half cylinder to make the protruding brick parts looking like half cylinder without making new object.

I know I can extrude and bevel edge. But I want to know easier way.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'Extrude and Bevel Edge' you mean something like this:

[image]

- With faces intact, and 'Face Dissolved' so no internal edges
- <kbd>E</kbd> Extrude one face, and then the other, snapping 'Active' to 'Vertex'
- Delete end-cap faces
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> the top face-selection with 'Clamp Overlap' set and a shape of 0.5, the default.
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (or whatever axis) the bevels back to the plane, snapping again.
- <kbd>M</kbd> merge by distance.

It's tricky to think of a quicker way, for a one-off. (Maybe someone will come up with one :)  )

Comment: I didn't mean it. but after many search, that way was the best thank you!